# How is xp calculated when overleveled?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing hardcore and always farming a lot, making sure I'm always very high level. But it seems I get much less xp because the mobs are much lower level than me.

Does anyone know how this reduction is calculated?

Comment: as long as you know the levels of the mobs you are fighting, the answer in @fbueckert 's link will provide a relative answer.